# How to keep events in own calendar app in sync with events added through google calendar app itself

Tags: java, android, kotlin, calendar, background-process

I'm working on an Android app with Android Studio which has its own calendar functionality. My question is more related to the planning phase.

My understanding is, that I can use "Calendar Provider" to read events into my app and also to write or edit events back into the users' original Google Calendar. However, I need to store the events within my app (like with an own Firebase database) for greater functionality, too.

What's missing is, how can I fetch events being added not through my app, but through the users' original Google Calendar? I cannot wait for the user to open my app and only then would trigger some sort of synchronization. It should be always in sync.

Is there some interface preferred for user apps fetching anything edited in Google Calendar? Are there any classes supporting that? Do I need some background process polling mechanism (not preferred and due to delayed fetching, wouldn't be actually in sync).

I'm trying to understand what would be the most common approach and what tools are available to achieve this.

Thank you very much!